# Finding the most colorful in a number of hex-colors

Tags: colors, ios7

in order to generate a dynamic color scheme for a webpage I read the dominant colors from an image. These include some very dark and some very light colors. All of which are not very good in being a base for a color scheme.

I need to select the most colorful/satured color from a set of colors.
I've looked at the HSL-values and thought about using those with the highest S and L values but this can also give me some very "dirty" colors.

Is there a good way the solve this? Somehow this seems like the way IOS7 selects a color from album art.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "dirty" colors?  Do you mean brown?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the HSL conversion with custom mapping to avoid any hues you don't want:

```
CGFloat hue; // in degrees, [0,360)
NSArray undesirableHueRanges = @[NSMakeRange(25, 20), NSMakeRange(180, 20)]; // e.g., you don't want colors with hues between 25º to 45º and 180º to 200º

for (NSRange undesirableRange in undesirableHueRanges) {
    if (hue > undesirableRange.location && hue < NSMaxRange(undesirableRange)) {
        if (hue > undesirableRange.location + 0.5 * undesirableRange.length) {
            hue = NSMaxRange(undesirableRange);
        } else {
            hue = undesirableRange.location;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to use the built-in color picker in most Mac apps (including Xcode) to play with different color modes:
[image: Standard Color Picker in Mac OS X]

Comment: Thx for the answer! So your strategy would also be to select the colors with the highest S and L values?

Comment: Yes, grab the most intense color(s) with the highest S and L, then use the H value as the hue in the code snippet in my answer.  For a uniform look, you could then replace the S and L with constants to maintain continuity no matter what hue is used (e.g., 100% L and 50% S).

Comment: May I suggest using another colour space? Something like L*A*B* Colour space is more directly what is wanted; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space.